# Working out thickness of a copper wire

Tags: resistance, resistivity

This was one of the questions for the repetition paper before the test.
"A lit light bulb has a resistance of 1320 Ω. It uses tungsten as a filament, and when hot, has a resistivity of 0.92 µΩm. Assume the filament is 2.0 cm long, how thick is then the filament?"

I work it out as follows:
Using the formula for resistance in conductors:

- ρ = Resistivity
- l = length
- A = cross section area
- R = resistance

  1. R = ρl/A
  2. A = ρl/R
  3. A = 0.92 µΩm * 0.02m / 1320 Ω
  4. A = 1.39×10^-11 m^2
  5. A ~= 13.9pm^2

That's just ridiculous. The answer given by my professor is 4.2µm^2.
What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

4.2 microns, not 4.2 microns squared.  Area is not a unit of thickness.  Divide your answer by pi, take the square root, and multiply by 2 to yield diameter

Answer (score 0):

1000 mm = 1 meter  &  1,000,000 mm^2 = 1 m^2

$$
A = 1.39 x10^{-11} m^2  = 1.39 x10^{-5} mm^2
$$

Assume the filament is circular wire...

$$
A = \pi r^2
$$
$$
r = \sqrt{1.39x10^{-5} / \pi} = \sqrt{4.44x10^{-6}} = 0.002106 mm
$$

Double the radius to get the diameter (thickness): 0.004213 mm = 4.213 microns.